# Mercurial Rollback and Rebuild

Tags: mercurial

We have 2 mercurial named branches, development and test. There have been many changes to development that were supposed to be merged up into test. At one point the changes were merged up and then rolled back. Then the merge may have been attempted in the wrong direction. The result is that we now have 2 branches with a recent common parent. And we still have changes in development that are not in test. But due to the mistakes we made and the common parent, merging development to test does nothing, i.e. it applies no changes.

If I'm willing to take test back a couple weeks, is it possible for me to switch to the test branch like this:

```
hg update <last good test revision>
```

Then 'graft to local' from dev the dozen or so changes we want to move to test, then merge in development to reset the common parent for test?

Is this a crazy plan or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just a dozen or so changes, you can indeed `update to good test rev` to start fresh and `graft to local` the commits you need to recreate the perfect branch.

Once and only once you are satisfied with your new banch head, use [this trick](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Keep_.22My.22_or_.22Their.22_files_when_doing_a_merge) to merge the two heads and ignore the bad `test` head. You need to have a single head on your branch.

Now you'd be in a state that `test` would hold all the changes from the `development` branch. I suggest you use the same trick once more to merge `development` in, to make the common parent for `test` you need, but without all the pollution that may have taken place in `development`. If it does not work, simply make a dummy changeset on `development` and retry the trick again (if it makes sense).

In the end, however, you don't seem too worried about the `development` branch being polluted by the `test` branch. Is it ok in that direction?

Comment: that worked. i do still have issues in reapplying changes, but this technique essentially rolled back the changes. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a crazy plan or is there an easier way?

Yes and yes. Short brain-powered (instead of ass-powered) plains are

**Plain A**

- Clone dirty repository into new without stupid, idiotic, brainless changesets (`hg clone -r LAST_GOOD_CSET`)
- Replace dirty repo by polished

**Plain B**

- Clone dirty repository into new (optional)
- Enable strip||histedit extension for **repository in question** (which you want to clean-up)
- **Read carefully extension-related docs** in order to use commands and workflow with brain, not blindly
- Remove erroneous changesets from repository
- Replace (if p.1 was done) dirty repo by polished

Comment: The problem with both of these methods is the last step, _replace the repo_. This involves synchronizing every one in your environment to re-clone the new repo, and use it instead of the old one. I would certainly not consider them as _simpler_ in any-size environment. Plus, you will still need to handle the changes from 'good rev' anyway. And all this hard work just to get a clean history without grafts?

Comment: @Vince - communication in any team is **a must**. I can't see problem in "Re-clone repo" broadcast message - if teamlead have brain and good quality

Comment: It is not just about communication, even if you can get all your off-site teams to align for this, for example, you will still be vulnerable to the accidental push from an old repo. And you know errors have happened before for them... Unless you additionally create a hook to prevent it, which is even more work, and another story.