# Reapply an ancestor change that's been backed out

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Ok, complicated mercurial scenario here, but every scenario in mercurial seems to get complicated.

We have 2 branches, dev and test. Lot of changes were made in dev and then merged into test like so:

```
hg update test
hg merge dev
hg commit -m "merging dev into test yo"
hg push
```

But then we realized that we didn't want ALL of those changes from dev. So I ran a backout like so:

```
hg backout --rev=<test rev of my commit> --parent=<test rev from before the merge>
```

This successfully backed out all the changes from the merge.

Problem is: I now want to graft in SOME of the changes from the dev branch, but it ignores them all, saying 'skipping ancestor revision X'

Is there a way to get those changes reapplied? (other than exporting and reimporting a diff?)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the actual state of your `test` branch, but if you are still close to the backout, I suggest instead to branch out of `test` **before** the initial merge. With this option, you won't inherit the parents from the other branch.

```
    @    new head
    |
    |
  o |    backout
  | |
  | |
  o |    bad merge
 /| |
| | |
o | |    other branch
| | |
| |/
| o      before merge
| |
| |
```

After that, graft what you need from `dev` and remerge the two heads by [discarding the backout completely](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Keep_.22My.22_or_.22Their.22_files_when_doing_a_merge) to maintain a single head.

Comment: I've done something similar. I had this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377982/mercurial-rollback-and-rebuild and doing a dummy merge to remove the extra head seemed to work. But then I read about merging favoring one parent and that seemed like the more direct way to do it.

Comment: I knew I saw your case before!

Comment: so it looks like the two solutions still have the same problem? the revs i want are in my history either way and i have to diff them back in yes?

Comment: Not really. The current solution will remove the parents if you start from before the merge. The `graft` will be possible, because the parents won't be in the history yet. Remerge the two heads only **after** you grafted your changes.

Answer (score 0):

The OP did specifically state they wanted to avoid using diffs, but this method does work quite well in some cases and others might find it useful. Also they didn't state WHY they wanted to avoid import/export (diffs).

Taken from [this blog](http://tumblr.christophercamps.com/post/6361581300/mercurial-how-to-reapply-a-revisionchangeset).

> You can reapply your change with this command.
>
> Let’s assume your change is in revision 78.
>
> Go to the root of your repo and run:
>
> `hg export 78 | hg import`

This will automatically re-commit whatever changed in revision 78. You can also specify options to NOT automatically commit, and/or you can export to a file and then import in a separate step.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-f` option to force `hg graft` to proceed anyway:

```
hg graft -f -r 12345
```

(Which was an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30500333/mercurial-way-to-avoid-skipping-ancestor-revision))